# Copying textured illustration from Illustrator to InDesign results in giant borders

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, copy-and-paste

I make math and geometry books.
I usually Have 1 to 3 .ai documents for each practicing book each with 1-100 artboard\s. 
Each artboard has 1 artwork.

My problem is when having a textured geometry shape copying it to InDesign results in huge borders and usually a bit crooked.

**I am wondering what is the best way to go about this kind of work.**

Important Note: I know nothing about how it works and what is the best approach here except for copying from Illustrator to InDesign.

Attaching screenshots for clarification:-

1. Original shape in Illustrator

[image]

2. After copying and pasting in InDesign (HUGE border)
   [image: In InDesign after pasting]

Also you can see it's bad:
[image]

if I copy it back from InDesign to Illustrator I get this:
[image]
[image]

This is after releasing clipping mask and still broken in some places
[image]

After moving the objects some left some right some up and some down, you can see it's getting out of were it is supposed to be
[image]

Fixing anchors one by one for each one of them
[image]

Now and only now, after fixing each drawing separately:

- Copying them from Illustrator to InDesign
- Copying the one I pasted in InDesign back to Illustrator
- Releasing clipping mask
- Moving the "little puzzle pieces" so the texture looks whole
- Fixing anchors everywhere it got out of the boundaries
- Copying it back to InDesign

Now the drawing looks in InDesign how it looked in the first picture in illustrator.

This happens with EVERY shape with textures I use from Swatches->"more"->Open Swatch Library->Patterns->Basic Graphics->Basic Graphics_Textures.

PLEASE help !!

Comment: Hi. You DON'T want to, but you MUST place the artwork.

Comment: Why DON'T you want to place the artwork? It is by far the more flexible method, imagine ever having to change the illustration. You'll end up having to copy/paste again, resize again, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was very young when started working and just did it the way they showed me to. Today I have more than 30 books each over 300 pages with tons of illustrations. Also, it means I need to save all my artboards as .epss and place each one of them - at least those with texture fills, not all of my artworks have fills, it is much easier to just copy paste and that way I can edit it in InDesign quickly if I need to -
In addition, it is very weird Adobe doesn't have a fix for that. In my humble opinion, It is not supposed to be like that.

Comment: That method is not the way InDesign was created to work. Its capacity to link to a placed file which is then updated when it changes, is one of its most important features imho. Editing vector artwork in it is possible, but it is explicitly not built for that, that's why it can be cumbersome. I think you are doing yourself and your workflow a big disservice by holding on to 'I've always done it this way'. My €0.02, no offense meant :)

Comment: "Also, it means I need to save all my artboards as .epss" -- not true. InDesign has been able to place native AI files since about its first version (plus or minus one or two). You need to grasp that *your current problems* are *because* you are sticking to a last century workflow.

Comment: I agree, is there a way to save an .ai document with let's say 50 artboards and then place all of them with one click?

Comment: @JulianBroude Yes. Actually 50 items is a joke. How do you think catalogues with thousand of items with main images, detailed images, illustrations, descriptions and price tables are made?

Comment: Hi again... Sorry if I was my 1st comment was a bit harsh. If you work with a single AI file with multiple artboards, there's an option you can tick while saving as: "Save each artboard to a separate file". About placing them in Indesign, there are many possible ways, but you need to be more specific about your workflow in order to get the best possible advise.

Comment: Everybody in the world is placing images and that's the normal workflow. Its like worldwide multinationals working in 20 languages on 100 pages full of pictures, do you think these people just copy paste 1000 photos or vector work, which can be huge files, directly into InDesign? :) Please consider it is likely you're just probably doing something wrong somewhere. Somebody showed you the wrong thing and you've built a huge volume of work on that very wrong approach. You need to go back to placing stuff and adjust your process. "I DON`T WANT TO PLACE" :))))

Comment: And: hey, Julian, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for a question that got us working those keyboards! We need controversial stuff like this to keep us on our toes, so good job so far. I recommend giving the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] a read, to understand the Stack Exchange model in general and this site in particular. Hope you enjoy the site in spite of a harsh welcome--we're rather passionate, here, sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Illustrator Basic Graphics_Textures, make your own patterns. In the image the same shape pasted in InDesign, on the left a shape filled with an Illustrator Basic Graphics_Texture (with all the issues you describe in the question) and on the right the same shape with a custom pattern fill:

[image: Pattern fill]

[image: Grid]

Add with an hexagon pattern

[image: hex]

### Making a pattern

Basic shape

[image: shape]

**Menu Object** > **Pattern** > **Make**

[image: pattern options]

Click Done

Select the shape, fill it with the pattern

Copy it and paste it in InDesign

[image]

Comment: This might work.
Could you please post a more in-depth explanation of how to accomplish that?

Comment: It works, I already tested, copying/pasting from AI to INDD and copying/pasting back from INDD to AI. The explanation about how to make an Illustrator pattern?

Comment: Sorry, I meant this might work for me. Not whether it works in general. I trust you tried it prior to replying to my problem. Much appreciated. Although after reading Adobes instructions on how to make a pattern, I made one just to try it out, unfortunately I got the same result. Same problem I described in the post.

Comment: In that case my gif is fake 

Comment: Danielillo, this is not what I meant. But fact is fact. I tried it and I had the same problem. Why would I lie? I tried it with hexagons btw.

Comment: Answer updated with an hexagon pattern, I guess you make a wrong step in the process.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to point me to your full process please?

Comment: Answer updated.